# How to get Request URI, request method in Spring AOP advice from the controller?

Tags: aop, spring-aop

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("api/postmethod")
public Response getResponse(@RequestParam String name, @RequestBody Object obj...){
....
}
```

Aspect:

```
@After("execution(* *(..))")
public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint){
...
}
```

How to get request uri -> ("api/postmethod") in Aspect advice?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will get the PostMapping value

```java
@Around("@annotation(postMapping) && within(com.aop.example.web.controller..*)")
public Object postMapping(ProceedingJoinPoint jp,PostMapping postMapping) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(postMapping.value()));
    return jp.proceed();
}
```

Explanation :

Pointcut expression  `@Around("@annotation(postMapping) && within(com.aop.example.web.controller..*)")` can be explained as follows

- a method annotated with `@PostMapping` and
- in any class within the root package `com.aop.example.web.controller`

For a post mapping like `@PostMapping(path = "api/postmethod")` , the aspect code should be modified to get `postMapping.path()`

Documentation reference for the "Passing Parameters to Advice" can be read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing)

Update :

Also note that the scope of the following pointcut expression is global . This can advice/target any method call within the application and would normally have undesired results.

```
 @After("execution(* *(..))")
```

It is recommended to keep the scope of the pointcut expression to target only what is required for optimal results.